# Converting a Win2D CanvasRenderTarget to a BitmapImage?

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

I'm trying to write a function which accepts my **ICanvasEffect** as a parameter (which in my case is a Win2D **BlendEffect**), and I want to convert the **CanvasRenderTarget** to a **BitmapImage** so that I can use it in a UWP **Image** control:

```
    private async Task<BitmapImage> GetBitmapImage(CancellationToken ct, ICanvasImage effect)
    {
        using (var target = new CanvasRenderTarget(CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice(), 320f, 240f, 96))
        {
            using (var ds = target.CreateDrawingSession())
            {
                // Draw the image with the supplied ICanvasImage
                ds.DrawImage(effect);
            }

            //await target.SaveAsync(outputStream, CanvasBitmapFileFormat.Jpeg).AsTask(ct);
        }
    }
```

As you see in the commented code, **CanvasRenderTarget** has a **SaveAsync** method I can use to save it to a Stream, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
    using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        await target.SaveAsync(stream, CanvasBitmapFileFormat.Jpeg).AsTask(ct);

        var bmp = new BitmapImage();

        stream.Seek(0);
        await bmp.SetSourceAsync(stream);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> As you see in the commented code, CanvasRenderTarget has a SaveAsync method I can use to save it to a Stream, but how?

If you want to save it to stream, you could refer to [Win2D samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D-Samples/).

There's many samples show that how to use [CanvasRenderTarget.SaveAsync()](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasRenderTarget.htm) method.

For example, [Win2D-Samples/ExampleGallery/Infrastructure/AppIconGenerator.cs#L217](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D-Samples/blob/2d6fed2cd4261447bc9c17c89559b7789efad8ae/ExampleGallery/Infrastructure/AppIconGenerator.cs#L217)