# Convert 32bpp to 8bpp UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to draw InkCanvas to an 8bpp image but when I try to do so the image convert itself to 32bpp, the lower I got was 24bpp but not 8bpp. Anyone can help me out? The image I am giving as input is an 8bpp BMP image created with paint.

```
        Image imgToEdit;
        InkCanvas inkCanvas;
        file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(Ambiente.imgBlankFirma);
        
        await file.CopyAsync(photoFolder, NomeFile, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        file = await photoFolder.GetFileAsync(NomeFile);

        imgToEdit = imgFirma;
        inkCanvas = inkCanvasFirma;
        
        if (inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes().Count <= 0)
        {
            errore = true;
            return;
        }

        var randomAccessStream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
        

        CanvasDevice device = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
        
        CanvasRenderTarget renderTarget = new CanvasRenderTarget(device, (int)inkCanvas.ActualWidth, (int)inkCanvas.ActualHeight, 96); //inkCanvas.ActualWidth inkCanvas.ActualHeight
        
        using (var ds = renderTarget.CreateDrawingSession())
        {
            var image = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(device, randomAccessStream);
            // draw your image first
            ds.DrawImage(image);
            // then draw contents of your ink canvas over it
            ds.DrawInk(inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes());
        }

        randomAccessStream.Dispose();

        // save results
        using (var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            await renderTarget.SaveAsync(fileStream, CanvasBitmapFileFormat.Tiff, 1f);
        }
```

Comment: I would assume the rendering is always done in 32bpp, so you might need to do the color conversion in a later step. See [32bpp to 8bpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355135/c-sharp-converting-32bpp-image-to-8bpp) and [render target to bitmapImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52226884/converting-a-win2d-canvasrendertarget-to-a-bitmapimage)

Comment: Hi, I already tried this solution but the problem is that with gif I can create an 8bpp image but can't upload it to the server where the image is needed in BMP format with 8bpp.

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to do the conversion by hand. It requires [direct pointer access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563038/fast-work-with-bitmaps-in-c-sharp) to the image data. So just create a new 8bpp (i.e. Format8bppIndexed) bitmap with the correct size for the conversion target. So converting the data should look something like this:

```
public static unsafe void Bgr24ToMono8(byte* source, byte* target, int sourceStride, int targetStride, int width, int height)
{

        for(var y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            var sourceRow = source + y * sourceStride;
            var targetRow = y * targetStride;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                var sourceIndex = (sourceRow + x * 3);
                var value = (byte)(sourceIndex[0] * 0.11f + sourceIndex[1] * 0.59f + sourceIndex[2] * 0.3f);
                target[targetRow + x] = value;
            }
        }
}
```

if you have 32bpp data it should just be a issue of changing `x * 3` to `x * 4`. Note that there is some confusion regarding Bgr vs Rbg, different contexts uses different terms for the same thing.

Note that this converts the bitmap to 8bpp **grayscale**. If you need 8bpp color indexed this will be much more work since you would ideally need to find a optimal color-map, find the closest colors in said map, and apply dithering to avoid banding. For this I would recommend some image processing library. I do not think there is any built in functions for this, and it is way to much work to demonstrate here.

Comment: sorry for the late reply JonasH but I don't know how to use that Parallel, and I don't know what is sourceStride and how to get it.

Comment: @SonicMast3r you can use regular for-loop instead of a parallel one. The stride is the number of bytes in a row, this should be available in some property, in for example [BitmapData.Stride](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.stride?view=windowsdesktop-5.0), check the link.

Comment: thanks a lot I will try this code maybe tomorrow.

Comment: Hi @JonasH I tried the code above but I can't use the library System.Drawing since I am on UWP.

Comment: @sonicMast3r For Wpf you can use [BitmapSource.CopyPixels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.copypixels?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) and/or writableBitmap to get access to the pixelData.

Comment: Hi @JonasH sorry for the late reply again, are you able to provide a complete code? since I never used pointers and I don't know how to use them. I was able to get the Stride by using this code [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/imaging#create-or-edit-a-softwarebitmap-programmatically).